# Different expressions for distance & displacement : $\int$$d$$|\vec r|$, $\int$$|$$d$$\vec r$|, and $|$$\int$$d$$\vec r|$

Tags: vectors, integration, geometry, distance, displacement

[image]I came across these expressions in my book. And the book says that all these are different from each other. 
The expressions are : $\int$$d$$|\vec r|$, $\int$$|$$d$$\vec r$|, and $|$$\int$$d$$\vec r|$

Are they different from each other?

I know that

- $|$$\int$$d$$\vec r|$ means magnitude of displacement,
- $\int$$|$$d$$\vec r$| means total distance,
- But what about $\int$$d$$|\vec r|$?

I think it should mean total distance too, but I’m not sure if $\int$$d$$|\vec r|$ and $\int$$|$$d$$\vec r$| have the same meaning, do they?

Edit : Some of the answers say that the question is not very clear, and that a little more explanation would help. I’m not sure what else to add, so I’m attaching a picture of that page

Comment: The name of this book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

---

In the above Figure-01 we see the quantities $\;\mathrm d\mathbf{r}, \Vert\mathrm d\mathbf{r}\Vert,\mathrm d\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\;$ for an infinitesimal displacement from point $\;\boldsymbol{1}\;$ to point $\;\boldsymbol{2}$.

Note that

1. $\mathrm d\mathbf{r}\;$ is an infinitesimal vector
2. $\Vert\mathrm d\mathbf{r}\Vert\;$  is an always non-negative infinitesimal scalar representing  the magnitude of $\;\mathrm d\mathbf{r}$, and
3. $\mathrm d\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert\;$  is a real infinitesimal scalar representing  the change of the magnitude of the position vector of point $\;\boldsymbol{1}\;$ to point $\;\boldsymbol{2}$. So, it's positive if increasing, negative if decreasing and zero if constant.

Let see now the integrals of these quantities along a curve $\;C\;$ as in Figure-02.

[image]

\begin{equation}
\Delta \mathbf{r} \boldsymbol{=}\int\limits_{1}^{2}\!\!\!\!\!\!C\mathrm d \mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{=} \mathbf{r}_2\boldsymbol{-
} \mathbf{r}_1
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Delta\Vert \mathbf{r}\Vert \boldsymbol{=}\int\limits_{1}^{2}\!\!\!\!\!\! C\mathrm d \Vert \mathbf{r}\Vert \boldsymbol{=} \Vert \mathbf{r}_2\Vert\boldsymbol{-} \Vert \mathbf{r}_1\Vert
\tag{02}\label{02}
\end{equation}

So, these quantities depend on the start and end points $\;\boldsymbol{1},\boldsymbol{2}\;$ and are independent of the curve joining them. I don't think that these quantities are useful in any case.

Now,
\begin{equation}
s_{1}^{2} \boldsymbol{=}\int\limits_{1}^{2}\!\!\!\!\!\! C\Vert \mathrm d \mathbf{r}\Vert \boldsymbol{=}\text{lenght of curve between points }\boldsymbol{1},\boldsymbol{2}
\tag{03}\label{03}
\end{equation}

---

**Note :**

This textbook is confusing. On one hand it's written that we have a vector 
\begin{equation}
\vec s \boldsymbol{=}\Delta \vec r \boldsymbol{=}\lim_{\Delta \vec r_{i}\boldsymbol{\rightarrow} 0} \sum\limits_{\boldsymbol{i=1}}^{\boldsymbol{i=n}}\Delta \vec r_{i}\boldsymbol{=} \int d\vec r
\tag{A}\label{A}
\end{equation}
and then this same integral of the rhs is used for a scalar, the length of the line joining points 1,2 
\begin{equation}
\int d\vec r\boldsymbol{=}\text{length of the line joining point 1 to 2}\boldsymbol{=}\vert \Delta \vec r\vert
\tag{B}\label{B}
\end{equation}

Comment: The two diagrams that you have used for the explanation make the difference between these three notations very clear. Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. So $\int d|\vec r|$ is basically a scalar, and is equal to the difference between the magnitudes of $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ But does it have a physical meaning?

Comment: @π times e : I don't think that $\int d|\vec r|$ has any physical meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an integral over radial distance.

Comment: This probably could use more exposition to be a useful answer.

Comment: I'd edit my question and attach a picture to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

It is the radial part of the total distance along some path. For example, for a circle there is an angular part of the total distance ($2\pi r$), but there is no any radial part contribution: $dr=0$.

Comment: Is this radial path (or radial distance) part of 'circular motion' ? I haven't studied circular motion yet, currently I'm staying motion in one dimension & motion in a plane. I'm not sure why it would show up in the book in the chapter I am studying. Do you think this expression can mean something else? Something related to what I am studying right now?

Comment: A motion in a plane may be circular: a point makes a two dimensional path around some point staying always at a certain distance $r=R$ from it.

Comment: My bad! Yeah circular motion is an example of 2D motion too. I meant to say that, I'm not studying circular motion right now. It is the next chapter. But this thing showed up in the current chapter that I am studying

Answer (score 0):

Notation matters. You have probably seen  $\int d|\vec{r}|$ written as $\int dr$, without vectors.

- In 1D, this is the same as $\int dx$. The letter for the disttance is not relevant.
- In more than 1 dimension, it's the integral along the radius. For example, in a circle, you'd integrate for all angles and also for all radii from 0 to $R$, for example. There you'd find that integral. $S=\int_0^{2\pi}d\varphi \int_0^R dr$

Comment: I just attached the pic, it’s exactly the same notation as I have used in my question. Now that I’ve attached the pic, can you please have another look at it? Thanks

Comment: Your picture is helpful to understand the two former cases, but you ask for a third case, $d|\vec{r}|$, which is not in the picture. It doesn't change anything, does it?

Comment: Actually...yeah, the third notation hasn't been talked about in the picture. It's just mentioned. Hence I asked it on here. Thanks for the explanation, I guess it is radial distance and will show up again in other chapters